# Angular dart click event on <a> href that is wrapped in shadow dom is retargeted to wrapper

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In Angular dart tutorial Chapter_06, the default router is based on hash. After change it to Html 5 push state, the route on edit button which is inside of view_recipe_component does not work.

After check a while, it turns out it is because, the  link of edit button is inside of shadow dom, so the click event is retargeted to <view-recipe> element (the wrapper of shadow dom). Then the DefaultWindowClickHandler can't get desired  element, therefore it does not fall into router's control.

So what should I do to handle this event retargeting in shadow dom in router of angular dart? or is there any existing solution in angular dart?